# Are there any cases where quantum has given insight for classical algorithms?

Tags: ds.algorithms, quantum-computing

To be more specific, has it ever happened that we've made some kind of significant improvement to a classical algorithm or problem as a result of some "trick" or insight gained from looking at quantum algorithms?

Comment: cf [classical computing embraces quantum ideas](http://www.simonsfoundation.org/quanta/20121218-classical-computing-embraces-quantum-ideas/) Wolchover/Simons inst

Answer (score 11):

There is at least one example that I can remember, but there are probably more that I am not aware of.

Recently, Maarten Van den Nest and Wolfgang Dürr found a  new [classical algorithm](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.2879) (arXiv:1304.2879) to approximate certain types of partition functions (of 3-body classical Ising models on two-dimensional lattices.  Their algorithm is completely *classical*, but several connections to *quantum* physics are employed in the design (read below). The algorithm was found to be exponentially faster than previously known algorithms that solve the same problem, at the time of writing*.

*I am ignorant of whether better classical or quantum algorithms have been found a posteriori.

So, there are at least **two quantum ingredients** used in the design of the VdND algorithm. On the one hand, the authors use a classical-quantum connection between classical Ising models and *topological quantum systems* (precisely, some color codes). On the other hand, the authors use classical techniques to *simulate quantum systems* in the derivation of the algorithm: in their proof, they first write a small quantum algorithm for the problem of interest; then, the authors show how to simulate the former quantum  algorithm efficiently on a classical computer, obtaining a classical algorithm (this is rather remarkable, in my view).

Answer (score 10):

[Quantum Proofs for Classical Theorems](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3376) by Andrew Drucker and Ronald de Wolf is a very nice survey on this topic.

One of the first classical results obtained by thinking about the problem quantumly was a communication complexity lower bound for the inner product function by [Cleve, van Dam, Nielsen and Tapp](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9708019).

Answer (score 1):

A couple more links on connections and analogies between quantum physics, quantum computation and (classical) computer science (to the already posted answers).

The survey paper of [Drucker and de Wolf](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.3376) is already mentioned.

A [presentation](http://quantum.phys.cmu.edu/QIP/simulation.pdf) on simulating quantum computers with (classical) probabilistic models (and references thereof).

A somewhat older paper on $PP$, $BQP$ and $PostBQP$ computation classes (arxiv, 2004).
[Quantum Computing, Postselection, and Probabilistic Polynomial-Time](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0412187)

Relations between (classical *hard*) computation and [renormalization techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) in statistical and quantum field theory (arxiv):

[Renormalization and computation I: motivation and background](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4921)

[Renormalization and Computation II: Time Cut-off and the Halting Problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3430)

[Renormalization group approach to the P versus NP question](http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/abs/cs/0608053v2)

Further connections in this direction in Baez, Stay (arxiv):
[Physics, Topology, Logic and Computation: A Rosetta Stone](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.0340)

A (thermodynamic) Turing Machine which can compute (quantum) Hadamard transforms (arxiv):
[A Thermodynamic Turing Machine: Artificial Molecular Computing Using Classical Reversible Logic Switching Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3273)

Finally a review on *Quantum Annealing and Computation* connections (arxiv, 2013):
[Quantum Annealing and Computation: A Brief Documentary Note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.1339)